# Coding a dynamic PHP css based progress bar - maths percent issue

Tags: php, math, equation

I'm coding a PHP progress bar that will update itself via a percent number that is given to it but I'm having issues working out the percents.

My code currently is as follows:

**PHP**

```
$percent = $_GET['percent'];

if($percent < 5)
    //low-image.jpg

elseif($percent > 95)
   //high-image.jpg

else{
$lowpercent = 100 - $percent;

$highwidth = 270 / 100 * $percent;
$lowwidth = 270 / 100 * $lowpercent;
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="mid-first" style="width:<?=$highwidth?>px;"></div>
<div class="mid-second" style="width:<?=$lowwidth?>px;"></div>
<div class="last"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.first. mid-first, .mid-second, .last{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    height:62px;
    }
.first{
    background:url(low.png);
    width:31px;
}
.mid-first{
    background:url(mid-first.png) repeat-x;
}
.mid-second{
    background:url(mid-second.png);
}
.last{
    background:url(high.png);
    width:32px;
}
```

**The Problem**

At the moment the percents are worked out slightly incorrectly, my maths brain seems to have been misplaced today...

There are 4 divs, the first and last div take up 5% each so 10%, the middle divs then equal the other 90%.

This means when the figure 50 is given passed in via the `$_GET` it will work out 50% of the middle bars not including the 5% first bar, which is wrong, it should take the first 5% into account and then work out the 50% pixel widths?

How can I change the maths behind the percent to fix the two middle bars so that when 50% is applied both middle bars are equal in pixels?

Comment: First things first: "math" is always singular. The Brits have it wrong. ;-)

Comment: Second: why are you converting them to pixels at all? Use percentages in the CSS and save yourself the computation.

Comment: @Blazemonger that's a good point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no good reason to use pixels at all. Wrap your divs inside a containing div and use percentages in your CSS.

PHP:

```
$lowpercent = 100 - $percent;
```

HTML:

```
<div class="barwrapper">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <div class="mid-first" style="width:<?=($percent-5)?>px;"></div>
    <div class="mid-second" style="width:<?=($lowpercent-5)?>px;"></div>
    <div class="last"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.first{
    background:url(low.png);
    width:5%;
}
.last{
    background:url(high.png);
    width:5%;
}
```

**OR**, if you don't want `first` and `last` to be taken away from the 100%:

```
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="barwrapper">
    <div class="mid-first" style="width:<?=($percent)?>px;"></div>
    <div class="mid-second" style="width:<?=($lowpercent)?>px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="last"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.first{
    background:url(low.png);
    width:30px;
}
.last{
    background:url(high.png);
    width:30px;
}
```

Comment: This works, but the problem is the first div is always 5%, so I need to work out the two percents taking that into account?

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean. Are `.first` and `.last` part of the 100% progress bar, or are they outside of the bar?

Comment: `.first` and .`last` are outside of the progress bar. If the progress bar is meant to be 50%, then `$percent = 50;` which means the html would be `width:50%;` but the first section is always 5% so it works out at 55% / 50%.

Comment: Okay, then use HTML similar to my second approach, so that only `.mid-first` and `.mid-second` are inside the `.barwrapper`.

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the width to integer as it can also be a floating point and you can calculate the width of the 2nd bar by simply substracting the 1st bars width from the total.

```
// We have already used 10 percents, so let's substract them
$percent = $percent - 10;

// We can't have negative percents, right?
if ($percent < 0) $percent = 0;

// Calculate 1st bar
$highwidth = (int) 270 / 100 * $percent;

// 100% - 1st bar = 2nd bar
$lowwidth = 270 - $highwidth;
```

Comment: You've just done algebra on the expression; it shouldn't change the actual result.

Comment: This doesn't take into account the actual problem which is the first 5% is already applied.

Answer (score -1):

You should convert $highwidth and $lowwidth to integers before writing them into the css or html. As it is they are floating point numbers.

I think this might work:

```
$percent = $_GET['percent'];

if($percent < 5)
    //low-image.jpg

elseif($percent > 95)
   //high-image.jpg

else{
    $highwidth = intval(270 / 90 * ($percent-5));
    $lowwidth = 270 - $highwidth;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't affect anything.